# Apps connect to Smartsheet using OAuth 2.0

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

Node.js

How to use access_token?

I'm making a request:

axios.post('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/token')...

response:

```
{

access_token: 'lkqgob9uf56d3vn0a358g4u199',

token_type: 'bearer',

refresh_token: 'd633gl7mlsw9cc7dnwlgmbwepe',

expires_in: 604799
}
```

What to do next with this information? And how to use it correctly?

I'm creating a client. But when trying to use it, is it always the same result? I think the token is not correct or I'm using it somehow wrong.

```
var smartsheet = client.createClient({

accessToken: 'lkqgob9uf56d3vn0a358g4u199',

logLevel: 'info',

});
```

But the result is always the same:

```
statusCode: 403,

errorCode: 1004,

message: 'You are not authorized to perform this action.',

refId: 'cdx056'
```

Why is that? Why is the access Token incorrect?

> You are not authorized to perform this action.

All I've realized now is that this token doesn't have enough access rights to make requests.
All I managed to do was get data about myself using the smartsheet_client code

```
.Users.get_current_user()
```

How do I get more rights? How exactly should this be prescribed and where?

Comment: You are not authorized to perform this action.

All I've realized now is that this token doesn't have enough access rights to make requests.
All I managed to do was get data about myself using the smartsheet_client code
.Users.get_current_user()

How do I get more rights? How exactly should this be prescribed and where?